# PHP include pathing problems

Tags: php, path, include

I know this question has been asked plenty of times, or at least related questions, but I just can't seem to figure it out. I haven't done too much PHP programming, I'm just trying to keep a simple template across all of the website I'm working on.

Basically there is a sidebar,banner,footer.php. I just do

```
<?php include('includes/banner.php'); ?>
```

That is when you're in the root folder - in index.php.
Inside banner.php is:

```
    <div id="banner">
        <img src="images/../banner.jpg" width="1000" height="120" border="0">
    </div>
```

That works fine and dandy for all the .php's in the root directory.

Now when I go to say directory A then to B I have another example.php ( So A/B/example.php ). Now if I try to use

```
<?php include('../../includes/banner.php'); ?>
```

It of course has the wrong path to the images. Since the code above is just pasted into the example.php with the image path of images/../banner.jpg. When it should be ../../images/../banner.jpg
How do I go about changing it so no matter how many directories deep I go, the banner image path is correct?

Just as FYI, I'm actually updating an old site for a friend. The layout of all the files and such ( and code, ugh ) are rather messy. So that's why I've been trying to clean it all up and make it a bit more organized and easier to update.

Thanks for help

Comment: just use absolute paths. For example, the `__DIR__` constant gets you the full path of the current directory, and you can use `dirname()` to get the parent directory and so on...

Comment: or set a path constant in your bootstrapper or config file.

Comment: Keep in mind that file paths for you php files are different than url paths. As a rule you should always have your resource calls, ( images, css, js, etc ) set to the root of the domain. eg `src="/images/banner.jpg"`. This way your php files never have to keep track of where they are organized versus where your resources are organized.

Comment: Well using @Lawrence idea, so would I create a config.php in the root directory and have it do <?php define('ROOT', DIR); ?> And then in say banner.php do echo '<img src="'.ROOT.'/images/banner.jpg" width="947" height="121" border="0">'; after including the config.php? But that doesn't work...hmm. I feel rather dumb heh. Even using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] instead of ROOT doesn't work. Because it just ends up doing localhost/Website/includes/C:/wamp/www/images/banner.jpg

Comment: Well...I feel dumb. I could just do src="http://www.mysite.com/images/banner.jpg" and the likes.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple idea use in Joomla / Wordpress / Cakephp & other open source.

Use:

require( dirname( __ FILE __ ).'/images/imagename.jpg');

Let me know if this works.

Thanks,
Munjal